# Is participation in different bug hunting programs viable career path and source of income?

Tags: salary, career-development, security

Is participation in different bug hunting programs viable career path and source of income?

More specific questions:

What are estimated, expected earnings of bug hunters?

How long one needs to train/learn to become one?

Are skills needed in bug hunting useful in general software engineering?

Is it true that there is lack of geographical barriers for such activity?

Comment: Depends on if you count exploit sales as "bug hunting".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is participation in different bug hunting programs viable career path
> and source of income?

As your sole source of income? Seem extremely unlikely, unless your expenses are very, very low.

To determine the viability of the plan, try it for a few months and see if it covers your expenses.

Comment: I live in Poland. Git Lab compensation calculator says that market rate is 1/3 of rate in San Francisco. I think earning half of that amount should be enough for me. Could you try to estimate what you mean by "very, very low"?

Comment: US has no jurisdiction in case of breach of contract, so very few companies will risk that just to save money. If they want to do that, you're now competing with India and China, and you will still lose.

Comment: @JanKowalski given that so far you seem to have made nothing from bug hunting so far, the very low is likely going to be "nothing".

Answer (score 1):

It is realistically impossible to answer a question this broad, but a few things to consider...

Bug bounty hunting is a bit like being an actor.  A tiny fraction of actors are successful enough to make a living solely acting.  A fair number can make enough for that to be their main source of income but have to supplement that income with a steady paycheck to make ends meet.  And then the is the majority that are primarily employed doing something else but act in the community theater and occasionally land a paying gig.  Does that make acting a viable career path?  Maybe.  Depends what you mean by viable and how well you tolerate risk.

Most of the skills are similar to what you'd learn if you were going into penetration testing in the security field.  That is a very specialized field of software engineering.  It's not very closely related to "normal" software development jobs but there is overlap.  There are plenty of folks whose day job is doing penetration testing that will do occasional work to get bug bounties.  How long it takes to get good at something like this is going to vary (and depend on where you start counting) but most people are going to spend several years after getting a computer science degree before they're likely to be proficient.